# how to show column value only one time if it is repeated and blank until different value comes in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

[image]

we have a simple table containing category and budget type column 
as show in the picture above I want to show CATEGORY only once and in place of next two CATEGORY 
there will be blank like this when I use select * query.

[image]

Comment: Query data and presenting data is two different things that is best performed by different tools. SQL server handles the query part. Not showing repeated values is task for the presentation layer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *could* do it like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Category ORDER BY BudgetType) = 1 
    THEN Category ELSE NULL END AS 'Category Caption'
    , Category
    , BudgetType
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Category, BudgetType
```

But as Mikael mentioned, this is - in most cases - really not the way it should be done. Just think that the client may, for example,  want to change the sorting within the categories, then the 'first' row within each category will be a different one.

Comment: I put +1 but not works for me, but is a unique example.

Comment: @delive, if you still can't get this to work, I think the best option is that you open a new question and post your code that doesn't work.

Comment: Although my problem was different I solve my problem thanks.