# SQL query to remove duplicate column values within distinct rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using MS SQL, I have tables "Table1" , "Table2" , "Table3" as mentioned below(might look like a mess, I dont know how to make a table better here).
I want the "Expected OutPut" as mentioned ant the bottom.

Want a SQL script to perform this action.

**Table 1**

```
FamilyID FamilyName
1        One
2        Two
3        Three
```

**Table2**

```
FamilyID UserID UserName
1        1      Name1
1        2      Name2
1        3      Name3
2        4      Name4
2        5      Name5
2        6      Name6
2        7      Name7
2        8      Name8
3        9      Name9
3        10     Name10
```

**Table3**

```
FamilyID RoomID RoomType
1        1      RoomType1
1        2      RoomType2
2        1      RoomType1
2        2      RoomType2
2        3      RoomType3
2        2      RoomType2
```

**Expected OutPut**

```
FamilyID UserName RoomType
1        Name1    RoomType1
         Name2    RoomType2
         Name3
2        Name4    RoomType1
         Name5    RoomType2
         Name6    RoomType3
         Name7
         Name8
3        Name9    RoomType2
         Name10
```

**EDIT:**
I tried [how to show column value only one time if it is repeated and blank until different value comes in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299860/how-to-show-column-value-only-one-time-if-it-is-repeated-and-blank-until-differe)  but the out put is not as i expected. It has duplications as sample shown below for FamilyID=1

**Result** from [how to show column value only one time if it is repeated and blank until different value comes in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299860/how-to-show-column-value-only-one-time-if-it-is-repeated-and-blank-until-differe)

```
FamilyID UserName RoomType
1        Name1    RoomType1
         Name2    RoomType1
         Name3    RoomType1
         Name1    RoomType2
         Name2    RoomType2
         Name3    RoomType2
```

**Expected OutPut**

```
FamilyID UserName RoomType
1        Name1    RoomType1
         Name2    RoomType2
         Name3
```

Comment: in oracle - i would do this with a user defined aggregate function.  I'm not sure if sql-server has a similar thing - but maybe that will help you search.

Comment: It's not really the thing you would like to do in a query. It is a part of presentation layer that should be handled by application, not database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a solution like this:

```
    SELECT T1.FamilyID,T2.UserName,T3RoomType FROM Table1 T1 
        JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.FamilyID =T2.FamilyID 
    LEFT JOIN Table3 T3 ON T2.UserID  =T3.RoomID 
    GROUP BY T2.UserID
```