# SQL Limit Results to each distinct but allow multiple other rows (Tree display effect)

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here is an odd one:
I need to do a report that spits out the primary row only once, but then allows every secondary row multiple times.

```
Example DATA

State | Name | Age
AL    |  Joe | 21
AK    |  Bob | 27
AR    |  Bart| 25
AL    |  Bart| 27
AK    |  Joe | 30
AR    |  Bob | 31
```

Would return as something like this:

```
State | Name | Age
AL    |  Joe | 21
      |  Bart| 27    
AK    |  Bob | 27
      |  Joe | 30
AR    |  Bart| 25
      |  Bob | 31
```

It sort of creates a "tree" display. Each state is listed only once, however all the secondaries are displayed as normal. Also, how would I expand this out so that if there were Multiple "Bart's", they would only display once, but the ages would be multiple times?

My initial thoughts were to do a series of sub queries, but I was still getting the primaries displayed.

Comment: I think you mean this - and take a look at the comments there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299860/how-to-show-column-value-only-one-time-if-it-is-repeated-and-blank-until-differe/20300041#20300041

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`, although I think such data manipulations should be done on the application side.  The resulting format is not consistent with relational tables and result sets.

```
select (case when seqnum_s = 1 then state end) as state,
       (case when seqnum_sn = 1 then name end) as name,
       age
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by state order by name, age) as seqnum_s,
             row_number() over (partition by state, name order by age) as seqnum_sn,
      from table t
     ) t
order by t.state, t.name;
```

Note that the `order by` is very important.  The definition of a row depends on its context (which is why this is a bad idea for anything other than output purposes).

Comment: Awesome, writing this up into the stored procedure now, will mark it as the answer when it works.

Comment: PERFECT, Thank you!

I was doing my bet to avoid using a cursor.