# How to show column value only one time if it is repeated and blank until different value comes in python

Tags: python

There is the same situation described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299860/how-to-show-column-value-only-one-time-if-it-is-repeated-and-blank-until-differe)! in SO but for sql. Im wondering how this could be done in python without using pandas **WITH MY CSV FILE which looks similar**

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Linked question's accepted answer does what you want: [KekuSemau's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20300041/2063361)

Comment: yes but in python and without using pandas

Comment: But I do not see him using `pandas`.  It is a SQL query. If you want to know how to run the sql query in python, you may search it on SO; you will find plenty of answers

Comment: yeah i know but i have the same situation in csv file. im sorry i should put this in my description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary and a list to solve the problem.

If you load your csv file into dictionary using the "category" as key and the "budget type" as data, you have  structure like this:

`data = {'category': ['regular','additional','additional1'], ....}`

where `data` is a dict and its value `data['category']` is a list with the values, you should solve your problem