# Executing a join while avoiding creating duplicate metrics in first table rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are two tables to join for an in depth excel report.  I am trying to avoid creating duplicate metrics. I have already separately scraped competitor data using a python script

The first table looks like this

```
  name   |occurances  |hits    | actions     |avg $|Key                             
---------+------------+--------+-------------+-----+----
  balls  |53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24
  bats   |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12
```

The competitor data is as follows;

```
      Key | Ad Copie   |
 ---------+------------+
   Hgdy24 |Click here! |
   Hgdy24 |Free Trial! |
   Hgdy24 |Sign Up now |
   dhfg12 |Check it out|
   dhfg12 |World known |
   dhfg12 |Sign up     |
```

I have already tried joins to the following effect, (duplicate rows metric rows created here)

```
 name    |occurances  | hits   | actions     | avg$|Key   |Ad Copie                    
---------+------------+--------+-------------+-----+------+---------
  Balls  |53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24|Click here!
  Balls  |53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24|Free Trial!
  Balls  |53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24|Sign Up now 
  Bats   |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12|Check it out
  Bats   |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12|World known
  Bats   |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12|Sign up
```

Here is the desired output

```
  name    |occurances  | hits   | actions     | avg$|Key   |Ad Copie                    
 ---------+------------+--------+-------------+-----+------+---------
   Balls  |53432       |  5001  |            5| 2$  |Hgdy24|Click here!
   Balls  |            |        |             |     |Hgdy24|Free Trial!
   Balls  |            |        |             |     |Hgdy24|Sign Up now 
   Bats   |5389        |  4672  |            3| 4$  |dhfg12|Check it out
   Bats   |            |        |             |     |dhfg12|World known
   Bats   |            |        |             |     |dhfg12|Sign up
```

Does anyone have a clue on a good course of action for this?  Lag function perhaps?

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense to me. There are no duplicate rows in your joined table.

Comment: There are duplicate metric rows in the table just under "I have already tried joins to the following effect"

Comment: You can try a method suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/20300041/6938602 but it is not a common practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is not a proper use-case for SQL. SQL is designed to create vies of data with all the fields filled in. When you want to visualize that data, you should do so in your application code and suppress the "duplicate" values there, not in SQL.